# Let $f$ a continuous function in $[0,1]$ that $f(x) > x\;, \forall x \in [0,1]$. Prove $\exists h \gt 0$ such $f(x) \gt x+h$, for $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, solution-verification, continuity

So I was thinking about going down a couple different roads but none seemed to work.

First of all I was thinking about using arithmetica of continuous function and looking for a limit on some $x_0 \in [0,1]$ but I'm not quite sure.

I know that since h is arbitrary then basically I can show $\lim h = 0$ but I am kind of lost as to how I can show this formally.

Another thing I was thinking was defining a function such as $g(x) = f(x) - (x+h)$ but that also didn't seem to work.

Anyway I would love some help!

---

EDIT:

I have sketched some proof and I would like to see if it is thorough enough:

Let us look at the helper function $g(x) = f(x) - x$, $g:[0,1] \to \mathbf R$.

From the datum $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$. Also, denote x is an elementarien function, thus continuous in $[0,1]$.

By arthmetica of continuous functions we have $g(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$.

From Weir Strauss theorem every continuous function in a closed segment has a minimum and a maximum. Thus let $x_0 \in [0,1]$ denote the minimum of $g(x)$ in $[0,1]$.

Denote, $g(x_0) \le g(x), \forall x \in [0,1]$.

From the datum we have $f(x) \gt x, \forall x \in [0,1]$ and specifically we have $f(x_0) - x_0 \gt 0$, thus implementing from the density of irrationals we have $h>0$ such that:

$g(x) \gt g(x_0) \gt h \gt 0$.

Thus meaning we have $g(x) > h, \forall x \in [0,1] \implies f(x) \gt x + h, \forall x \in [0,1]$.

As needed.

Comment: $f(x)-x$ is a positive continuous function, so it has a positive minimum.

Comment: @geetha290krm this is based on Wier Strauss theorem of a continuous function in a closed segment?

Comment: Every continuous function on $[0,1]$ has  a minimum (and a maximum).

Comment: @geetha290krm alright thank you very much I'll sketch up some proof and edit my question.

Comment: Duplicate targets found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%20%3E%20x%24%2C%20AND%20content%3A%24f(x)%20%3E%20x%2Bh%24)

Comment: "thus implementing from the density of irrationals we have $h>0$ such that" no need to bother density of irrationals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g=f-x$, so $g>0$ and is continuous on this compact set $[0,1]$, hence can attain its maxima and minima. The minima can't be zero, otherwise contradicts with $g>0$, hence the minima is some positive number, define it as: $\min g=a>0$. Now take $h=a/2$ and it is done.